# How to integrate current auth system with oauth

Tags: oauth

Current auth system has a auth table:

uid | username | password

What should I do if I want to enable the user to sign up and login with facebook, twitter account.

Create a different table to store the tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a separate table with at least the following fields:

uid|system(facebook or twitter)|private token|public token

The system field would have to link to another table that holds the public/private application tokens for each system. This allows you to add in additional systems (Google Plus, Linked in, etc.) without having to change the DB model.